# Biased Clamper Circuits

Tags: voltage, capacitor, diodes, bias, diode-clamp

> I have been tasked to design a clamp circuit to clamp the negative extreme of a periodic input waveform to **−5 V**. I can use diodes, zener diodes, and resistors of any values required. I will assume a **0.6 V** forward drop for all diodes and that the Zener diodes have an ideal characteristic in the breakdown region. 
> Powersupply voltages of **±15 V** are available.

For Input Voltage having maximum amplitude greater than 5 Volts, I just have to do positive clamping. For example, with **V<sub>in</sub>** = **6 * sin(100 * pi * t)**, the entire waveform will move up by 1V. Hence my DC or Q point will be **1V**.

However, I am struggling with two things.

- If Input AC Voltage is less than **5V**, for example, assuming **V<sub>in</sub>** = **4V**, in that case, the negative peak will be at **-4V**, meaning that in order to clamp this to **-5V**, I have to go down by 1V. How do I achieve this here?
- What is the use of that **15V** DC source here? How does this affect the circuit allowing me to achieve my goal?
  I have attached the solution that I have from my Professor, but I could not grasp his explanation unfortunately.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]